# Expression Within ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

In ArcMap I add 2 tables, join on a field then run an attribute query to return any of the joined tables records that are not null in a particular field - all works OK.

I would like to build this into a model but the model gets stuck when selecting attributes. When I add the same SQL statement "[field] is not null" click verify it says there is an error with the expression but this same expression works when I run manually in ArcMap.

Any ideas why the statement works in ArcMap but not in ModelBuilder Select Tool

Comment: Found the problem. I had to partially run the model so it had values to work with.